# SoapFault Exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'user_name' property

Tags: php, soap, sugarcrm

I am having some trouble issuing a SoapClient call using PHP, and I'm getting the error you're seeing in the title.

I am pretty sure it's something "small" I'm missing, but I checked similar questions and no answer found for my problem.

Let's get straight to the code:

```
    $client = new SoapClient("path_to_wsdl");
    var_dump($client->__getFunctions()[1]);
    var_dump($client->__getTypes()[73]);

   //I need to call function in position [1], which is login, and I need to declare struct in position [73], user_auth

    class user_auth {
        function user_auth($username, $password) {
            $this->user_name = $username;
            $this->password = md5($password);
            $this->version = 1;
        }
    }
    $user = new user_auth("username", "password");
    $params = array("user_auth" => $user);
    print_r($params);
    $response =$client->login(array($params)); //This is where I get the exception!
```

What I get from running this PHP is:

string(70) "set_entry_result login(user_auth $user_auth, string $application_name)"

string(74) "struct user_auth { string user_name; string password; string version; }"

Array ( [user_auth] => user_auth Object ( [user_name] => username [password] => md5(password) [version] => 1 ) )

So the error is that in Object, I don't have "user_name" field, but it looks like I have it!

Hope you guys can give me some help about this.

Sincerely,

Andrea

Comment: Try using SoapVar : http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapvar.php

Comment: Can you provide an example using SoapVar?
I have tried it, but the error persists.

        $soapvar = new SoapVar($user, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "user_auth");
 $params = array("user_auth" => $soapvar);
 print_r($params);
 $response =$client->login(array($params));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it's solved, look at the differences in code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("path_to_wsdl");

class user_auth {
    function user_auth($username, $password) {
        $this->user_name = $username;
        $this->password = md5($password);
        $this->version = 1;
    }
}
$user = new user_auth("username", "password");
$params = array($user);
$response =$client->__soapCall("login",$params); //Now working!
```